# Place style inside Custom Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm creating the custom control. And suddenly faced a question: why to put control's style separately from the control?
I mean that using the standard way you must: derive from base control (for example, from TextBox) and add a style for it in general.xaml.
But why can't we do just like this:

```
<TextBox x:Class="CustomTest.CoolTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.FontSize" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class CoolTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CoolTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Update #1**

I'm not writing my own library but creating a custom control inside my main executable. Application support themes but they differ only by colors. So each theme is a set of brush resources and my style will refer them using *DynamicResource*.

What I want to know is the drawbacks of that solution. I mean performance, simplicity of usage and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF allows changing themes at runtime, means the style shall be stored separatly from the controls. Futhermore the control shall be lookless when designining in order to other programmers to have their custom styles though somewhere there should be a default style which must be stored separatly in a Generic.xaml file. If your app doesn't support changing themes then you can define the style wherever you wish.

If you are writing a library of custom controls I suggest you to stick to standards.

Here is a link how shall a custom controls be created:

http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: DynamicResources are slower than StaticResources and shall be avoided.

Comment: Agree! But in current project there are not many controls and this slowdown is invisible.

Comment: That is correct. Use DynamicResources only when a resource needs to be found at runtime. For anthing else use StaticResources.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *dev hedgehog's* answer about performance, I found the following drawbacks:

1. Style object is own for each **instance** of control. So you end up with number of clones of the same Style object.
2. You cannot override style using BasedOn property. Only completely replace is possible.